# Issue while calling custom google search tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-search, google-custom-search

I am using the google custom search api, But I don't want the google search default text box so for the same reson I have craeted a new text box and one button. On click of my custom button I am fetching search key value from my custom text box and putting in to the google search default text box. But in my javascript function I am unable to perform click event of the google search submit button. I know the class name of google search submit button now how can I do the click event in my java script function?

google search dubmit button class name is "gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2"

Now in the following method I need to perform the click event of the above class.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById('gsc-i-id1').value = document.getElementById('customTextBox').value;
 // here I need to perform click event for "gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2" class
}
</script>script>
```

I have the demo example in the following link,

http://jsfiddle.net/3L4fd63g/3/

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tag so heres one option working with a submit of a form so the enter key on the textbox will also perform the search.

also, to perform a click you just need to call `.click()`

```js
// Make sure in jsFiddle you have selected option onLoad.
(function() {
  var cx = '017643444788069204610:4gvhea_mvga'; // Insert your own Custom Search Engine ID here
  var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
      '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();

$(function(){

  $('#search').submit(function(e){
    $('.gsc-input').val($('#customTextBox').val());
    $('input.gsc-search-button').click();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```css
.search-box{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="search">
  <input type="text" id="customTextBox"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Click me" />
</form>

<div class="search-box">
    <gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox>
</div>

<gcse:searchresults></gcse:searchresults>
```

Comment: I am not geeting the results iin your demo. Also I tried in in the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3L4fd63g/8/ it is not working. Can you please update in jsfiddle and update the same

Comment: click on the 'run code snippet' above works. also, see this fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/3L4fd63g/9/